# Creating a new table in Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I have a sample data set as below. I would like to calculate `Additions_at_Cost` as `Month Current - Previous Month` and create a new table for each group. How to get around with this ? Many thanks in advance.

```
 EVALUATE
Var mydf2 =
DATATABLE (
    "Group A", STRING, "Variable", STRING, 
    "MonthFY", STRING, "Value", CURRENCY,
    {
        { "Gorup A", "Accum_Dep","Apr FY23", 5000 },
        { "Group A", "Accum_Dep","May FY24", 6000 },
        { "Group A", "Accum_Dep","Jun FY24", 7500},
        { "Group A", "Accum_Dep", "Jul FY24", 8500 },
        { "Gorup A", "Accum_Dep Dispositions Impairments","Apr FY23", 10 },
        { "Group A", "Accum_Dep Dispositions Impairments","May FY24", 10 },
        { "Group A", "Accum_Dep Dispositions Impairments","Jun FY24", 1000},
        { "Group A", "Accum_Dep Dispositions Impairments", "Jul FY24", 1000 },
        { "Gorup A", "Dispositions","Apr FY23", 999 },
        { "Group A", "Dispositions","May FY24", 999 },
        { "Group A", "Dispositions","Jun FY24", 5000},
        { "Group A", "Dispositions", "Jul FY24", 5000 },   
        { "Gorup A", "Additions_at_Cost","Apr FY23", 10000 },
        { "Group A", "Additions_at_Cost","May FY24", 20000 },
        { "Group A", "Additions_at_Cost","Jun FY24", 50000},
        { "Group A", "Additions_at_Cost", "Jul FY24", 60000 },
        { "Gorup B", "Accum_Dep","Apr FY23", 5000 },
        { "Group B", "Accum_Dep","May FY24", 6000 },
        { "Group B", "Accum_Dep","Jun FY24", 7500},
        { "Group B", "Accum_Dep", "Jul FY24", 8500 },
        { "Gorup B", "Accum_Dep Dispositions Impairments","Apr FY23", 10 },
        { "Group B", "Accum_Dep Dispositions Impairments","May FY24", 10 },
        { "Group B", "Accum_Dep Dispositions Impairments","Jun FY24", 1000},
        { "Group B", "Accum_Dep Dispositions Impairments", "Jul FY24", 1000 },
        { "Gorup B", "Dispositions","Apr FY23", 999 },
        { "Group B", "Dispositions","May FY24", 999 },
        { "Group B", "Dispositions","Jun FY24", 5000},
        { "Group B", "Dispositions", "Jul FY24", 5000 },   
        { "Gorup B", "Additions_at_Cost","Apr FY23", 10000 },
        { "Group B", "Additions_at_Cost","May FY24", 20000 },
        { "Group B", "Additions_at_Cost","Jun FY24", 50000},
        { "Group B", "Additions_at_Cost", "Jul FY24", 60000 }
        })
Return mydf2
```

Expected Answer

```
                    AprFY23      MayF24       JuneFY24                  JulyFY24
Goup A Add at Cost   10,000     20,000    30,000(50,000 -20,000)  10,000(60,000-50,000)
Goup B Add at Cost   10,000     20,000    30,000(50,000 -20,000)  10,000(60,000-50,000)
```